# Getting error 800c0008 while login Microsoft Account after reseting my Lumia 525

Tags: microsoft-account, nokia-lumia-525, reset

After re-setting my Lumia 525 I tried to add my Microsoft Account. While doing that I got an **error 800c0008** saying "Try after sometime". I tried after sometime and the issue still existing. How to fix this issue?

Comment: Is the time and date correct (or near correct)?

Comment: Yes! Time and date are correct.

Comment: I am using Lumia 525.i am reset my phone.i can't go to sign in the Microsoft account because the problem if this error code 800c0008
Plz help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed this issue by going to Data Sense settings and turning off the option "Restrict background data usage". After turning it off, Microsoft account and other accounts have been successfully added.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've been playing around with the brains of the phone somehow judging by reading your previous posts.... download the nokia recovery tool and that will resore your phone as it should be

http://www.nokiapoweruser.com/lumia-software-recovery-tool-updated-to-version-5-0-5-changelog-how-to/

Answer (score -3):

the numbers appears randomly i mean some times it is changed what i found is you have to create an account on the phone. hear how you can do:
1 go to the app list
2 select settings
3 select email+account
4 create an account or enter the email address if u have and password

some times turn off Data sense to work the above step

Comment: It has no relation with the phone's Microsoft Account. This is just an email account.